# Trace minimization problem in MATLAB

Tags: optimization, matlab

objective function:  $\min_{X} F(X)$

constraint : $\operatorname{trace}(CXDX^H)\ge\alpha$

where A&C&Dis a matrix of $N\times N$ and X is matrix of $N\times N$ and F(X)=trace$(AX^HX)$

how this problem is solved in matlab?

Comment: This might be a better fit at SO.

Comment: I doubt this can be easily solved. The constraint is very likely non-convex. (It would be convex if, for instance, $C$ is negative definite and $D$ is positive definite, or vice versa.) Similarly, $F(X)$ would be convex if $A$ is positive definite, but otherwise, it is not convex either.

Comment: Yes sir A is a positive definite matrix. and consider C and D as you given then how it can be solved?

Comment: Given your discussion of this problem on the CVX forum, it is clear that the problem is not convex. It has a convex objective, but a nonconvex quadratic constraint. There are heuristic approaches to solving problems with nonconvex quadratic constraints, but there is no ready-made software for MATLAB that will help you, I don't think. See [this reference](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/relaxations.pdf) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize all calculations and feed it into MATLAB's solver.

It won't give you the optimal solution only Local Minima as this is not a convex optimization problem.